# How do I resolve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-state

This is my code. Unable to resolve this error I am getting in the console and nothing is printed when I run the file.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

class TableGen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tableData: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const res = axios
      .post(
        'https://us-central1-stockmarketcharting-8c469.cloudfunctions.net/server/performance/getbest'
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ tableData: res.array });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.tableData.map((row) => {
          return (
            <Grid item sm={6}>
              {row.data.price}
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default TableGen;
```

I am getting a Cannot read properties of undefined error. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think res.array is undefined. Can you share an example response?

Comment: Are you sure you want to make a post request instead of a get request?

Comment: @Jballin res is an object and res.data is an array.

Comment: So shouldn’t you be using res.data when setting state?

Comment: If I do that I'm not able to access the elements. I get a "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')". But the previous error is gone, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response of axios call comes with data object so everything you'll get is inside it like array, price, items , etc ..
i would try to log res.data to the console and see the response object, there you'll find out what it contains and the required data you need :

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

class TableGen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tableData: [],
      // add some flag
      isErrorFetching: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const res = axios
      .post(
        'https://us-central1-stockmarketcharting-8c469.cloudfunctions.net/server/performance/getbest'
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("response ===>>> ", res.data);
        this.setState({ tableData: res.data });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({ tableData: [], isErrorFetching: true });
      })
  }

  render() {
    if (isErrorFetching) {
     return <div>Something went wrong!</div>
    }
    if (!tableData.length) {
     return <div>There are no items found!</div>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.tableData.map((row) => {
console.log("row ::: ", row);
          return (
// ensure there is a price property
            {row?.data?.price && (
             <Grid item sm={6}>
              {row.data.price}
             </Grid>
            )}
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default TableGen;
```

Let's assume the res.data is an array, then you cannot get the price from the item of array, then let's log the row to the console to see if it contains price or any other required data .

Comment: The array response is like this. https://ibb.co/mtBDnTx. Is there a problem in the way I'm iterating through it using map? I tried the above changes. The error persists.

Comment: okay there is no problem with that but i don't see any price out there!
so it works fine, and that error about price is clear now!

Comment: Btw you get that error because row doesn't have data property !!
please focus of the item of array and see what for properties it has

Comment: Even if I change it to another attribute it's not working. But anyway thank you for all your help.

Comment: Wait haha change this :
`this.setState({ tableData: res.data.array });`
to this :
`this.setState({ tableData: res.data });`

Comment: and also this :
`{row?.industry && (<Grid item sm={6}>{row.industry}</Grid>)}`

Comment: You are right. Didn't need to do {row.data.name}. Thank you so much, it worked.